# Making a unicode file into a different file

Tags: python, json, twitter, text, unicode

Currently, I have a Python script that opens a file and appends a Tweet from Twitter to a file. Part of my listener for stream listener goes like this:

```
class listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, api=None, path=None,outname='output',MAX_NUMBER_OF_TWEETS=100,TWEETS_PER_FILE=10,progress_bar=None):

        self.api = api       
        self.path = path
        self.count = 0
        self.outname = outname 
        self.progress_bar = progress_bar
        self.MAX_NUMBER_OF_TWEETS = MAX_NUMBER_OF_TWEETS
        self.TWEETS_PER_FILE = TWEETS_PER_FILE

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data) 
        with open(filename,"a") as fid: 
           print>>fid,all_data
```

However, the file that is printed out is a Unicode file. 
How would I get let's say a text file or a JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode *is* a text file. What you are probably seeing is the output in the wrong output code (Say, the file could be in UTF-8 and your console might be in another coding).

Python let's you select the coding of the output file if you use the [io module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html). On opening a file for write, you can select the coding you want to use. If you want to type on the screen, you should use the correct for the screen. (In Linux, use `set` to check the locale. No idea how to do that in Windows)

Comment: Its not that I don't get proper text because everything in the unicode file is in the format that I want it to be in. What I am trying to get is a .txt file or a .json file, not a unicode file with no extension.

Comment: Well, you can just rename the output file to `something.txt`, in that case you have a .txt file with unicode in it. There is no extension which indicates the coding of the file. If you don't like unicode characters inside the txt file, then you can use the `io` module to convert it to pure `ASCII`, or `Latin-1`, but then you can encounter tweets with characters which are not representable in that coding. There is no difference if you decide to use JSON. By definition it uses utf-xx coding. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#page-9